# Trying to read a text file in javascript but keep getting status =0 and no text

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use JavaScript to read the contents of a text file.  The text file is in the root c drive folder.  XMLHttpRequest.status is returning 0 and no text.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function readFile() {
        readTextFile("file:///C:/SafetyEvents.txt");
    }

        function readTextFile(file)
        {
             //alert("reading file: " + file);
             var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
             rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
             //rawFile.send();
             rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()  //not getting here
             {
                 alert("state " + rawFile.readyState);
             if(rawFile.readyState == 4)
                 {
                     if(rawFile.status == 0)
                 {
                     alert("status " + rawFile.status);
                     }
                     if(rawFile.status == 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
                     {
                         document.getElementById("fileContents").innerHTML = rawFile.responseText;
                 var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                         alert("text: " + allText);
                 document.getElementById("fileContents").innerHTML = allText
                         }
                     }
                 }
            }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="readFile()">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <p id="fileContents"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can't use `FileReaer()` on `file:///` "domains", only HTTP(s), or maybe on some browsers, you can only read() files in the same folder as the running html page. also, windows uses backslash...

Comment: interesting...an example on stackoverflow shows that you can.